# How to specify precision when reading in variables using netCDF4 in Python?

Tags: python, netcdf4

I am trying to read in ADCP (ocean current speed) data and clean/process it. The data are given in `x` and `y` component velocities from the `.nc` file I am using, so I must calculate the resultant speed and angle from the components. I am having precision issues when using np.square to square the individual elements of the component velocity range that are within the same magnitude of the error of the instrument itself.

I suspect that this error is due to the length of the raw data (e.g. `-0.02162790298461914`). I would like to set the precision of the raw data to `0.001` (the inherent error of the ADCP) and recalculate to see if the calculation error decreases. Is there a way to manually set the precision when reading in the data using `infile.variables['variable'][:]`, and if so, how would I go about that? Or might there be a numpy method that has less error than `np.square(array)`?

An individual example of the error:

```
x_vel = -0.02162790298461914
y_vel = -0.3665189743041992
```

manually calculated `total_vel = 0.36588029782633846` (this manual calculation was done with python using `m.sqrt((-0.3665189743041992) ** 2 + (-0.02162790298461914 ** 2))` )

sript calculated `total_vel` using `np.sqare` and `np.sqrt` on the numpy arrays = `0.3671565353870392`

script code: `total_v = np.sqrt(np.square(x_vel) + np.square(y_vel))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that I simply overlooked a typo for sign convention... The output using the numpy functions is in fact correct. The issue stemmed from -1 ** 2 != (-1) ** 2 and my misuse of parentheses in calculating... Guess we all have to spend a few hours hunting down brain farts every once in a while

The manual input should have been `m.sqrt((-0.3665189743041992) ** 2 + (-0.02162790298461914) ** 2)`

instead of `m.sqrt((-0.3665189743041992) ** 2 + (-0.02162790298461914 ** 2))`

(notice the grouping of parentheses on the second term...)